# C# htmlagility pack, capturing redirct

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

HI all, this one is really simple (I hope).  I'm using htmlagility pack to do my webcrawling.  So what happens if I input url whatever, that then directs me to a new url, how do I capture that new redirected URL?

If htmlagility pack doesnt have a way, can someone suggest another method?

Comment: Just trying it would be faster than asking the question and waiting for an answer. You would know very quickly if it was possible and how the HTML Agility Pack would behave.

Comment: I have tried, cant seem to use WebResponse technique in htmlagilitypack

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create your HttpWebRequest you can set `AllowAutoRedirect` property to true and it will automatically follow any redirects you have.

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");  
myHttpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections=1;
myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect=true;
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse=(HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

you can find more info at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx)

Comment: I did see this and +1 for mentioning it, I was just hoping that there was a swift way in htmlagilitypack.

Comment: I had a look and couldn't find anything in html agilitypack

Answer (score 9):

Using the HtmlWeb class that comes with the Html Agility Pack, you can tweak the request before it's actually executed, like this:

```
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    web.PreRequest = OnPreRequest;
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://wwwblablahh.com");


private static bool OnPreRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: this is not working for this : 


<meta http-equıv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.pratikev.com/fractalv33/pratikEv/pages/home.jsp">

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - Of course. What you show is not an HTTP redirect, it's an HTML redirect. For an HTML redirect, you can use an XPATH expression: doc.SelectNodes("//meta[@http-equiv='refresh']") .. etc..